# ogr2ogr loading gml file error : PQconnectdb failed, SSL off

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to import `gml` files to `postgres` by following the steps on [AstunTechnology/Loader](https://github.com/AstunTechnology/Loader)

`loader.config` file is updated as;

`ogr_cmd=ogr2ogr --config GML_EXPOSE_FID NO -append -skipfailures -f PostgreSQL PG:'dbname=postgres host=data01 user=postgres password=XXXXXXX' $file_path`

I get the following error;

```
Loading: U:/Data/AB/data\AddressBasePremium__001.gml
ERROR 1: PQconnectdb failed.
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "fe80::79b6:629d:9c4e:96d5%6", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off

ERROR 1: PQconnectdb failed.
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "fe80::79b6:629d:9c4e:96d5%6", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off

ERROR 1: PQconnectdb failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "fe80::79b6:629d:9c4e:96d5%6", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off


ERROR 1: Couldn't establish a database connection
ERROR 1: PQconnectdb failed.
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "fe80::79b6:629d:9c4e:96d5%6", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off

ERROR 1: PostgreSQL driver doesn't currently support database creation.
Please create database with the `createdb' command.
ERROR 1: PostgreSQL driver failed to create PG:dbname=postgres host=data01 user=postgres password=XXXXXXXXX
```

After going through some of the answers on StackExchange, the `pg_hba.conf` file was changed as following;

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

Next the server was stopped and started;

```
waiting for server to start....2019-10-26 13:31:XX.XXX BST [10928] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2019-10-26 13:31:57.977 BST [10928] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2019-10-26 13:31:57.994 BST [10928] LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
2019-10-26 13:31:57.994 BST [10928] HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "log".
 done
server started
```

After the changes still I am getting the error as mentioned above.

I tried adding `listen_addresses = '*'` into `pg_hba.conf` but then I cannot start the server with error; `pg_ctl: could not start server`

Can you please help me to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IP4 connections you have:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

but for IP6 you'll need the equivalent sub-net mask `::/0` like:

```
host    all             all             ::/0               trust
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much. I added these 2 lines to `pg_hba.conf` and it worked.